# PHP com sockets

Tags: php, socket

Como faço para usar **PHP** com socket? Pode ser qualquer tipo...
Preciso de criar notificações e um chat.

Já tentei usar de diversas formas, mas nunca consigo. :/

Comment: Pode colocar na pergunta uma das formas que você tentou? Será mais fácil para identificar qual é a sua dificuldade. Você já estudou a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.sockets.php)? No que ficou em dúvida e o que não funcionou?

Comment: Boa noite. Poderia melhorar os detalhes da pergunta? Geralmente, quando se fala em `socket` em PHP, podes estar se referindo à linha de comando. Ou você quer fazer um chat via HTML? Se for o segundo caso, você pode usar Websocket.

Comment: Sim, eu desejo usar o segundo caso (HTML). Mas não estou conseguindo fazê-lo. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simples servidor TCP/IP**

Este exemplo mostra uma simples troca de informações do servidor. Alterar as variáveis address e port para o conjunto da sua configuração e execução. Você deve então conectar o servidor com uma linha de comando similiar a: **telnet 192.168.1.53 10000** (onde o endereço e a porta partem da sua configuração). Algo que você digitar então irá sair no lado do servidor, e mostrar isso para você. Para desconectar, digite 'quit'.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Permite que o script fique por aí esperando conexões. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Ativa o fluxo de saída implícito para ver o que estamos recebendo à medida que ele vem. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '192.168.1.53';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() falhou: razao: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() falhou: razao: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() falhou: razao: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() falhou: razao: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Envia instruções. */
    $msg = "\nBem-vindo ao PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "Para sair, digite 'quit'. Para desligar digite 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() falhou: razao: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: Você disse: '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

**Simples cliente TCP/IP**

Este exemplo mostra um simples, one-shot cliente HTTP. Isso simplesmente conecta à uma página, envia um cabeçalho de requisição, mostra a resposta, e sai.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<h2>Conexão TCP/IP</h2>\n";

/* Obtem a porta para o serviço WWW. */
$service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

/* Obtem o endereço IP para o host alvo. */
$address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

/* Cria o socket TCP/IP  */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() falhou: razao: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

echo "Tentando se conectar a '$address' na porta '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() falhou.\nRazao: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

$in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$in .= "Conexão: Fechar\r\n\r\n";
$out = '';

echo "Enviando solicitação HEAD HTTP...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.\n";

echo "Resposta de leitura:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo $out;
}

echo "Fechando socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.\n\n";
?>
```

> Leia mais sobre sockets:
>
> [Documentação - SOCKETS](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.sockets.php)